# Does this java homework involve boolean? How to implement the loop?

Tags: java, loops, binary

I am almost a complete beginner.

I need to write a program that asks user to input a binary number, verifies whether the number is in fact binary, and then count the number of 1's in the binary number.

So far I have this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class BinaryWords 
{
    public static void main( String [] args )
    {
    int binaryNumber1;
    int binaryNumber2;
    int binaryNumber3;
    int binaryNumber4;
    int binaryNumber5;
    int binaryNumber6;
    int binaryNumber7;
    int binaryNumber8;
    int binaryNumber9;
    int binaryNumber10;
    int binaryNumberWhole = binaryNumber1 + binaryNumber2 + binaryNumber3
            + binaryNumber4 + binaryNumber5 + binaryNumber6 + binaryNumber7
            + binaryNumber8 + binaryNumber9 + binaryNumber10;

    if 1<binaryNumber1<0

        then final int SENTINEL = binaryNumber1;


    System.out.println( "This program verifies a binary number"
            + "representing a word and then" 
            + "counts how many 1's are in that number");

    System.out.println("Please enter a binary number representing a word");
```

Not pretty, I know!  I am confused as to how to read each binary number in the binary sequence and check for 0 or 1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why does your code suddenly omit all braces? And you will need to use logical AND to combine multiple comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `String` variable and use it to receive the input from the user. When they do you loop through every character of this string checking if it is a number and if it is 0 or one.

You need to learn how to get an input from the console so take a look on how to use the `Scanner` class on java.

So, you have a `String`, a `for loop` and two `if` conditions (maybe you choose to use an try block instead to convert it to a number)

As you are learning I will not provide the code to it so you can be able to figure out yourself.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I am trying to learn, thanks.  I will follow your advice though.

Comment: Thank you for this.  This was the guidance I needed, but I also happened to get input elsewhere.  This is a good outline.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can read user input as String and then analyse each character of that String if its not equal to 0 or 1.

In the same loop you can also count how many characters are 1's.

Do you know how to read user input in Java?

Best regards,

Miguel

Comment: Thanks, Miguel.  I am working on this.  I think I am at the point that you are suggesting.